# Angular2 why getters if wen can define public properties

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, public

Why duplicating code to define getters when we can access properties directly from template ?

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use getters. They're only useful if you need to execute some logic every time the property is accessed.

Example: Your property's value is derived from the value of other properties in your code (and these other values change over time). You can't store the value in the property once and for all, since it has to be re-calculated every time the other values change. (Think grand total in a shopping cart component, which is obtained by adding the price of each product multiplied by the number of units.)

In essence, a getter property is analog to calling a function. But in a template some prefer writing `{{ myValue }}` vs `{{ getMyValue() }}`.

Another use of accessors in Angular is to implement a setter to react to value changes for a property. The documentation has an example of a component whose @Input changes and the component needs to react to that. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#parent-to-child-setter.

Comment: angular also has its own `get` syntax/keyword for creating getters, in that case the getter wouldn't have a name like `getMyValue()`, instead the name of the getter would be `public get myValue() { return this._myValue; }` and the field could be `_myValue` for example. - Using/calling a getter in angular doesn't require `()` after it. So, actually inside the template/view you can't see the difference really between a getter and a public field. My point: your example of `getMyValue()` is just a method that acts as a getter, but it's not a real angular getter. But how does it compile ?